How to get uniswap v3 price tick?

I am planning to get the price range from users (lower price and higher price ) but if the user provide lower price as 0.00029991932 and higher price is 0.00033985099 then how can I get the lower tick and uppper tick form these for mintNewPosition.I mean how to calculate lower tick and uppper tick from the low price and high price?
Any one knows please help
